# What's the exterior derivative of the two form: $x \,dy \wedge dz + y \,dx \wedge dz + z\,dx \wedge dy$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-forms

What's the exterior derivative of the two form: $x \,dy \wedge dz + y\, dx \wedge dz + z\,dx \wedge dy$?

I saw some calculations on this site and I'm pretty sure that the answer is $3\, dx\wedge  dy\wedge dz$ , however, this conflicts with the answer posted on here, [Exterior derivative of a 2-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109630/exterior-derivative-of-a-2-formin),  which I get $ dx\wedge  dy\wedge dz$.

How do I do this correctly? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am no expert, however I think it would be:  $\frac{\partial}{dx}x dy \wedge dz \wedge dx + \frac{\partial}{dy} y dx \wedge dz \wedge dy + \frac{\partial}{dz} z dx \wedge dy \wedge dz  = dy \wedge dz \wedge dx  + dx \wedge dz \wedge dy  + dx \wedge dy \wedge dz $ , does this make sense?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks.

Comment: as I see it, my comment only works for 1-forms (you have a two form given), Captain Lama's answer handles the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you just use that $d(\alpha\wedge \beta) = d\alpha\wedge \beta + \alpha\wedge d\beta$, and in particular $d(fdg) = df\wedge dg$ since $ddg = 0$.

So $d(xdy\wedge dz) = d(xdy)\wedge dz + (xdy)\wedge ddz = dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$.

Likewise, $d(ydx\wedge dz) = dy\wedge dx\wedge dz$ and $d(zdx\wedge dy) = dz\wedge dx\wedge dy$.

Now $dy\wedge dx\wedge dz = -dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ and $dz\wedge dx\wedge dy = dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$.

All in all the sum is $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$. You most likely forgot the signs.

Comment: How would the answer change if we were talking about the 2-form $$(x-a)dy\wedge dz+(y-b)dz\wedge dx+(z-c)dx\wedge dy$$?

Comment: It would not, since $d(ady\wedge dz) = 0$, and likewise for the other two additional terms.