# exterior derivative of wedge of two one-forms

Tags: exterior-algebra

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be $k$-forms, then, where $d$ is the exterior derivative, we have
$$ d (\alpha \wedge \beta) = d \alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^k (\alpha \wedge d \beta)$$

However, in many cases, e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1694182/198235), or [this textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319969919) (pg. 147), I've come across the equation, when $\alpha, \beta$ are $1$-forms,

$$ d (\alpha \wedge \beta) = d \alpha \wedge \beta + \alpha \wedge d \beta $$

The second equation doesn't agree with the first one, since $(-1)^k=-1$ in our case,where $k$=1.

What am I missing?

Comment: The latter formula is incorrect. The other sources might have gotten away with it, because in their examples, $d\beta = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, That make sense